# ZStack is laying out views differently when adding another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this code:

```
ZStack {
    if let captionText = captionText {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(captionText)
                    .font(.small)
            }
    }
    
    user.username()
}
```

It looks like this (ignore the profile picture):

[image]

The 'admin' text position is very strange, it should be leading, equally as the username. When I add a `HStack` around the captionText, the `username` is... centered. This is totally unlogical for me:

[image]

and the code:

```
ZStack {
    if let captionText = captionText {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text(captionText)
                    .font(.small)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }

    user.usernameFormattedText()
}
```

but the caption text is now correct. Any ideas why a `ZStack` changes the position of a `View` when a *different* `View` updates its position?

I fixed the problem by wrapping everything in `HStack`s and `VStack` with `Spacer`s to make it work, but it is horrible. I am hoping I am just doing something wrong and the fix is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are just missing an `alignment: .leading`  – and I don't understand why you use `ZStack` instead of `VStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var username = "[anonymous]"
    var captionText: String? = "Admin"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(username)
                    .font(.headline).italic()
                
                if let captionText = captionText {
                    Text(captionText)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 300)
        .background(.gray)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I want the username to be centered horizontally and the captionText to be at the bottom, that's why I used a ZStack

Comment: you want the username centered, and the captiontext leading aligned to that? – I updated my answer.

Comment: or do you want the username centered VERTICALLY ?

Comment: I just went with the VStack as you mentioned, it doesn't look 100% the way I wanted, but it's fine. The ZStack is doing some weird stuff